# Simply connected and direct products

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

A topological space $X$ is *simply connected* if and only if $X$ is path-connected and the fundamental group of $X$ at each point is trivial, that is, $\pi(X,x_0) = 0$ for any $x_0 \in X$.

Now, we know that if $X,Y$ are simply connected, then $X \times Y$ is simply connected. My question: **Is it also true the converse?**

Since $X \times Y$ is path-connected we get $X,Y$ are path-connected. There exist a way to assert $\pi(X) = \pi(Y) = 0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$.

Comment: I know that result... But I´m not sure that $\pi(X \times Y) = 0$ implies $\pi(X) = 0$.

Comment: Try counting the size of the groups on either side of the isomorphism.  We know that $\pi_1(X \times Y)$ has one element, so...

Comment: So....... It thas implies $\pi(X)$ only has one element?

Comment: Yes.  The product of two groups is trivial iff the two factors are trivial.